# Embedded jetty not running outside eclipse ide also jar is not containing webapp or we root folder

Tags: jetty

I am having a issue when I run jetty in embedded mode after creating my jar file. It works from the same location where jar is created because it can locate src/main/webapp folder but when I copy my jar it's not running. And when I open my jar it doesn't have src/main/webapp everything is at root level.

1. First of all why is it creating everything at root level any specific reason?
2. Can I run my jar from Java command line if there is no src/main/webapp, if yes then in that case what shud be my webcontext resource look like in my main class

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
String webappDir = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("applicationContext.xml").toExternalForm();
webappDir = webappDir.substring(0, webappDir.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
String webXmlPath = webappDir + "WEB_INF/web.xml";

WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext(webappDir, contextPath);
context.setDescriptor(webXmlPath);
context.setResourceBase(webappDir);
context.setClassLoader(new WebAppClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), context));
```

Run from IDE or Jar both works.